# Why does sudo sometimes asks for a different sudo user?

Tags: sudo, authentication, openldap

I have all my boxes setup to authenticate against OpenLDAP. When I log on with the local user (`localmin`) and run a command like

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

it sometimes asks for the password of `localmin` but sometimes at random asks for the password of `firstname.lastname` (some user account (also member of sudoers) from the OpenLDAP database)

Why is this and how do I prevent it?

Comment: UIDs are the same?